# UnsatisfiedLinkError when using aar-file in Expo project

Tags: android, react-native, expo, aar, unsatisfiedlinkerror

We've experienced issued when trying to link and *.aar file on Android when using Expo. We get everything to compile and build but on most Android devices we end up with a runtime UnsatisfiedLinkError crash where our native code doesn’t find the aar binary,

We use a library called [Movesense mdslib](https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-mobile-lib/src/master/android/). We’ve been able to get https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mds (which itself uses mdslib) working with some minor tweaks in a non-Expo React Native project, but we want to use Expo for it’s superior developer experience.

With Expo we've tried both managed and bare workflows with both react-native-mds and our own https://github.com/zmartrest-ai/expo-mds which is inspired by the former. We’ve also tried aligning the architecture we’re building for (removing x86_64 to align with mdslib), different combinations of locations for the *.aar-file, different ndkVersions.

A minimal repo is set up at https://github.com/lordspace74/zrn which contains a *react-native* project with *expo modules* installed and manual linking of *expo-mds*.

This issue is also posted to [Expo](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21228) (where environment and output from Logcat is included)

Any help would be highly appreciated!